# How to update data once it has been imported in excel file? PHPExcel, CodeIgniter

Tags: php, excel, codeigniter

I am importing excel data and inserts it to my mysql database and that is already successful, what I am trying to do now is to update after I have inserted.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Example: My total data is 32 so if I have imported excel again it should also be 32 but if there's any changes in my excel sheet it should be updated.

Controller:

```
function import()
{
 if(isset($_FILES["file"]["name"]))
 {
    $path = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    $object = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($path);
    foreach($object->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet)
    {
        $highestRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow();
        $highestColumn = $worksheet->getHighestColumn();
        for($row=16; $row<=$highestRow; $row++)
        {
            $studentID = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1, $row)->getValue();
            $name = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(2, $row)->getValue();
            $grade = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(5, $row)->getValue();
            $subject = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(2, 8)->getValue();

            if(isset($studentID)){
                if($name != null){
                    $data[$row] = array(
                    'studentID'  => $studentID,
                    'name'  => $name,
                    'grade' => $grade,
                    'subject' => $subject
                    );
                }
            }else{
                if($name != null){
                    $dataUpdate[$row] = array(
                    'studentID'  => $studentID,
                    'grade' => $grade,
                    'subject' => $subject
                    );
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
    
        if(isset($data)){
            $this->loading_model->insert($data);
        }

        if(isset($dataUpdate)){
            echo 'Something';
        }

        echo 'Data Imported successfully';
        
    } 
}
```

Model:

```
function insert($data)
{
    $this->db->insert_batch('tbl_college_grades', $data);
}

function update($data)
{
    $this->db->update_batch('tbl_college_grades', $data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It starts with the data you're importing. You would need a way to uniquely identify each row in the excel data. "Email", for example could be a good candidate for this if you can make it available. Or maybe a composite of "name" and "subject" are unique?

Your database will need to have this same column (or composite) set as unique also to match your excel data that you're importing.

Then you can do an UPSERT which will automatically check if the row you're about to insert already has a match given the unique key, and will update that row with the current data (which may be new) and create a new row if it doesn't find a match.

Comment: hello sir, I have updated my controller and tried to do the method you advised. Can you please help me further if there's a mistake I have done because it still inserts even though I have tried to conditioned it to update.